# Reference to superclass

Tags: c++

I'd like to use a visitor pattern in combination with smart pointers, but it seems that the compiler can't detect the subclass and match the appropriate function.

I've written an SSCE showing the problem:

test.hpp:

```
class Visitor;
class Area {
public:
    virtual void visit(const Visitor& visitor) = 0;
};

class Area1 : public Area {
public:
    virtual void visit(const Visitor& visitor);
};

class Area2 : public Area {
public:
    virtual void visit(const Visitor& visitor);
};

class Visitor {
public:
  virtual void visit(const Area1 &area) const = 0;
  virtual void visit(const Area2 &area) const = 0;
};
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.hpp"

void Area1::visit(const Visitor& visitor) {
    visitor.visit(*this);
}

void Area2::visit(const Visitor& visitor) {
    visitor.visit(*this);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "test.hpp"

class FooVisitor : public Visitor {
    virtual void visit(const Area1 &area) const {
        std::cout <<"visit area1" <<std::endl;
    };
    virtual void visit(const Area2 &area) const {
        std::cout <<"visit area2" <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::shared_ptr<Area> p(new Area2);
    FooVisitor visitor;
    visitor.visit(*p);
    return 0;
}
```

The line **visitor.visit(*p)** gives this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:17:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘FooVisitor::visit(Area&)’
main.cpp:17:21: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:6:18: note: virtual void FooVisitor::visit(const Area1&) const
main.cpp:6:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Area’ to ‘const Area1&’
main.cpp:9:18: note: virtual void FooVisitor::visit(const Area2&) const
main.cpp:9:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Area’ to ‘const Area2&’
```

How do I help the compiler realize that visit(const Area2&) should be called without resorting to attempting dynamic_cast to each of the subtypes?

Comment: The Visitor visits, I'd call the `visit` functions in the Area classes `accept` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can't work, as the type of `*p` is indeed `Area&` (based on the type of the pointer). However, you're using it wrong. To correctly apply the visitor pattern, you should call the `visit()` defined in `Area`, to get the correct dispatch:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::shared_ptr<Area> p(new Area2);
    FooVisitor visitor;
    p->visit(visitor);
    return 0;
}
```

That's the purpose of the `Area::visit()` function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your visitor class has two visit(...) methods:

void visit(const Area1 &area) 
void visit(const Area2 &area)

So to explicitly call the visit method from a visitor object you need to pass a reference/pointer to either a Area1 object or Area2 object. **Since you pass a Area object, you need to do the dynamic_cast for this to work.**

BUT the previous answer you got summarizes the actual problem in the code -> **you are using it wrong.** your code should do something like

```
Area *p = new Area2();
FooVisitor v;
p->visit(v);
```

This way make use of the polymorphism in you code.